# non admin can't view 'rewrite results' in lightbox

Tags: views, javascript

I created a view to display thumbnails and what i'm trying to accomplish is:

when you click on the thumbnail, it opens the node content in lightbox. I get it to work perfectly when i'm logged in as admin, but as soon as I logout and click on the image thumbnail, lightbox opens, but it's blank white. If i inspect the lightbox, the content isn't being pulled in for some reason (but it's only when i'm logged out as admin). permissions are set for anonymous users to see content. odd thing is...if i just linkthe image to a larger image using imagecache and lightbox, anonymous users can see it just fine. it's the rewrite results that they can't see. It's driving me crazy. i can't find any answers online anywhere that would cause this.. i'm using D7

Any ideas?